# Resuming the partial downloaded files from another site like a Download Manager

Tags: download-manager

Looking for any software which downloads the single file hosted in different multiple websites matching the same size, version, name which includes matching AOO, KEYS and PGP/ASC keys and having SHA256 / MD5 hash values.

So when downloading interrupts from one site doesn't affect the partial chunks of downloaded file after resuming again from another website. But not at all start over again